# Setting Notepad++ find results style

Tags: search, colors, notepad++

I am using a dark scheme with a custom language / syntax highlighting. This results in a "find result" window which is very hard to read. Where does Notepad++ find results style get set, so I can adjust these settings (does it affect the regular code coloring scheme?)?

**Solution:**

Settings > Style Configurator - Language: "search result"
If it doesn't work for you, check the global override settings

Comment: Close the question if you've found the solution.

Comment: @micke No. Do not **close**. You can answer your own question and then later **accept** the answer.

Answer (score 11):

In `Settings > Style Configurator` go to the `Language column`, `Search Result` option and change the colors there.

If this doesn't work, check the global override settings.

[image]

Comment: If the style settings are not remembered when you close and run again Notepad++, execute it with the admin privileges (right click > Run as administrator), make the changes, then close the program. The settings will be properly saved; then you can run Notepad++ as usual.