# Notepad ++ how to configure search box to display ALL text

Tags: notepad++

I have imported a custom XML file in Notepad++ which allows me to analyse log files using a nice color coded theme. When I perform a "find" and the find box comes up the results inside the box only highlight the words I search for and the rest of the lines/data is blacked out. As you can see in the image, I searched for the word, "exception" - the find box found one instance, but blacks out the rest of the line. I have been unable to figure out what controls how the find results are displayed. I need to be able to see the whole line with the search string highlighted or bolded. In the previous version I believe it was bolded.

[image]

Comment: Find results don't have syntax highlighting ...

Comment: That may be. Now that I think back, the results did not match perfectly BUT I was able to see them. The way it is now the only words I can see in the search box is the words or strings that I searched for. I need to be able to see the whole line with the search strings highlighted. It did work that way before but for the life of me I can't seem to figure out what controls that aspect search box.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include a screenshot of what you see and say what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

Install below

notepad++ xml tools libraries from sourceforge

Comment: More Details?? Link??

Comment: reinforce your answer, you could be right, but 2 short lines answer do not help.

Comment: XML tools 2.4.7 downloaded but it gave me a error saying "This plugin is not compatible with the current version of Notepad ++"

Comment: Do you have a link to one that will work with my version of Notepad++

Comment: Well if it needs 2 lines than its fine. Actually when I saw this Question it was written as it cannot find the syntax and it was working before he attempt to reinstall it  also the screen shot was not  there. The Question is edited and Changed now for styling and GUI offcourse it will take to you different Direction but for functionality it needs tools library.

Comment: @syed - You still should fix this answer.  The revisions done to the question didn't really change it.  Even if it did then you should consider updating the answer so it does apply or simply delete the answer.  Even against the original question this answer is below acceptable standards.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here:

[Setting Notepad++ find results style](https://superuser.com/questions/401434/setting-notepad-find-results-style)

This allows you to adjust all of the coloring/highlighting aspects of the find box. Also, I still had to make one change in the Global Styles language under "Default Styles" to finally get the lines to appear. HTH someone else.